# How to get the current data of the marker that is in array list?

Tags: android, android-volley, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, infowindow

I am currently working with the google map. I already show the markers and the title and snippet of the marker.

Now my problem is when I click the info window it will be redirected to a new activity and get the data of the marker that was clicked. Here is my code:

```
public class FindApartment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener,GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener {


public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String VERIFICATION = "verification";
private static final String TAG_APARTMENTNAME = "apartmentName";
private static final String TAG_CATEGORY = "Category";
private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price_month";
public static final String LAT = "latt";
public static final String LNG = "longt";



MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
CameraPosition cameraPosition;
LatLng center, latLng;
String verification, apartmentname, category, price, id;


GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
MapView mapView;

String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_apartment, container, false);


    mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map1);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    mapView.onResume();


    return rootView;
}



@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}


@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions myMarker = new MarkerOptions();
    myMarker.position(latLng);
    myMarker.title("me");
    myMarker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(myMarker);

    //move map camera
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,17));
    getMarkers();

}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {


    mGoogleMap=googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);


    if(mGoogleMap!= null){

        mGoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);

                TextView textName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textName);
                TextView textViewPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPrice);
                TextView detail = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.detail);

                LatLng ll = marker.getPosition();

                textName.setText(marker.getSnippet());
                textViewPrice.setText(marker.getTitle());
                detail.setText("click to see full detail");

                return view;
            }

        });




    }
```

I'm using Android Volley and the array is on the Stringrequest. How can I get the data of the marker that was clicked on info window?

```
 private void addMarker(LatLng latLng, String category, final String price, final String id) {

    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title(price);
        markerOptions.snippet(category);
        markerOption(verification, markerOptions);


        mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);


    }


public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
   id = marker.getId();
    String snippet = marker.getSnippet();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), InfoWindowActivity.class);


    startActivity(intent);

}



private void markerOption(String verification, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
    if(verification.contains("pending")) {
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
    }
    else {
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
    }
}


private void getMarkers() {
     String url = Server.URL2 + "markers.php";

    final HashMap<String, String> apartmentID = new HashMap<String, String>();
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("Response: ", response.toString());

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                String getObject = jObj.getString("apartments");


                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(getObject);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    verification = jsonObject.getString(VERIFICATION);
                    apartmentname = jsonObject.getString(TAG_APARTMENTNAME);
                    category = jsonObject.getString(TAG_CATEGORY);
                    price = jsonObject.getString(TAG_PRICE);
                    id = jsonObject.getString("userID");

                    apartmentID.put(ID, id);

                    latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LAT)), Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LNG)));

                  //  Adds a data marker to show to google map
                    addMarker(latLng, category, price, id);



                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_json_obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), InfoWindowActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("snippet", snippet);
intent.putExtra("id", id)
... //put all your info here 
startActivity(intent);
```

Access that data on next activity for example in onCreate or wherever you need it.

```
String snippet = getIntent().getStringExtra("snippet");
int id = getIntent().getIntExtra("id");
...//get all your info here
```

Is it what you were looking for? Question is not completely clear..